# How to delete the dot (face) in a middle 'blender guru anvil

Tags: modeling

Dont know how to delete this thing, there's a face or dot showing in the middle and I think this is the reason why my model look like ugly when I turn submesh

Comment: It would help if you show an image of whatever it is that you call "dot" or "this thing" or "ugly"

Comment: Also, you can search among the many questions that particular video has generated: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Anvil

Comment: @cegaton how can i post picture, need some help on this thing this is my first time using blender stock exchange

Comment: You can use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: @cegaton https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105945/normal-dot-in-edge-selection-outside-of-face-weird-subdivision this is the same with my problem

Comment: it looks like the center of a face when you're in Edit/Face mode, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/